# keras combine pretrained model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I trained a single model and want to combine it with another keras model using the functional api (backend is tensorflow version 1.4)

My first model looks like this:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras as keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
input = Input(shape=(200,))
dnn = Dense(400, activation="relu")(input)
dnn = Dense(400, activation="relu")(dnn)
output = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(dnn)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

after I trained this model I save it using the keras model.save() method. I can also load the model and retrain it without problems.

Now I want to use the output of this model as additional input for a second model:

```
# load first model
old_model = keras.models.load_model(path_to_old_model)

input_1 = Input(shape=(200,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(200,))
output_old_model = old_model(input_2)

merge_layer = concatenate([input_1, output_old_model])
dnn_layer = Dense(200, activation="relu")(merge_layer)
dnn_layer = Dense(200, activation="relu")(dnn_layer)
output = Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(dnn_layer)
new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
new_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]
new_model.fit(inputs=[x1,x2], labels=labels, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

when I try this I get the following error message:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_1/kernel
 [[Node: dense_1/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@dense_1/kernel"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense_1/kernel)]]
 [[Node: model_1_1/dense_3/BiasAdd/_79 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_68_model_1_1/dense_3/BiasAdd", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: This blog post about using pre-trained models with Keras may be useful: http://innolitics.com/10x/pretrained-models-with-keras/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this in following steps:

1. Define function for building a clean model with the same architecture:

   ```
   def build_base():
       input = Input(shape=(200,))
       dnn = Dense(400, activation="relu")(input)
       dnn = Dense(400, activation="relu")(dnn)
       output = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(dnn)
       model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
       return input, output, model
   ```
2. Build two copies of the same model:

   ```
   input_1, output_1, model_1 = build_base()
   input_2, output_2, model_2 = build_base()
   ```
3. Set weights in both models:

   ```
   model_1.set_weights(old_model.get_weights())
   model_2.set_weights(old_model.get_weights())
   ```
4. Now do the rest:

   ```
   merge_layer = concatenate([input_1, output_2])
   dnn_layer = Dense(200, activation="relu")(merge_layer)
   dnn_layer = Dense(200, activation="relu")(dnn_layer)
   output = Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(dnn_layer)
   new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I solved my problem after I loaded my saved model I set some GPU configs     session = tensorflow.Session(config=config)
        keras.backend.set_session(session) after that the weights get lost because I set another session. If I set my session config and than I load my model I can reuse it. Only question now is if the weights of the pretrained model get changed or how I set them to be constant.

Comment: Hi do you mean
    
    merge_layer = concatenate([output_1, input_2])

Comment: Hi I get the following error when i try to add multiple training data to fit() ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a pre-trained/saved CNN model called `pretrained_model` and you want to add a densely connected layers to it, then using the functional API you can write something like this:

```py
from keras import models, layers

kmodel = layers.Flatten()(pretrained_model.output)
kmodel = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(kmodel)
kmodel_out = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(kmodel)
model = models.Model(pretrained_model.input, kmodel_out)
```